# Ошибка с input shape в keras: "expected dense_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 135, 240, 3)"

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, keras

Всех приветствую. Пытаюсь обучить свою (почти первую) модель.

Есть массив x_train. Информация о нем:

> x_train shape: (1, 135, 240, 3) x_train len: 1

```
train_data = np.load(file_name)

X = np.array([i[0] for i in train_data])
Y = [i[1] for i in train_data]

print("x_train shape:", X.shape)
print("x_train len:", len(X))
```

А так же y_train. Информация о нем:

> y_train shape: (1, 9) y_train len: 1

```
train_data = np.load(file_name)

X = np.array([i[0] for i in train_data])
Y = [i[1] for i in train_data]

print("y_train shape:", np.array(Y).shape)
print("y_train len:", len(Y))
```

Сам класс нейросети:

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras

class NeuralNetwork():
    def __init__(self):

        self.model = keras.models.Sequential()
        self.model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1024, input_shape=(8, ), activation="sigmoid"))
        self.model.add(keras.layers.Dense(512, activation="sigmoid"))
        self.model.add(keras.layers.Dense(9, activation="softmax"))

        opt = keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01)
        self.model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=opt,
                      metrics=["accuracy"])


    def FitModel(self, epoch, trainX, trainY):
        self.model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=epoch, batch_size=32)


    def Predict(self, image):

    predictions = self.model.predict(image)

    choice = np.argmax(predictions[0])
    return choice
```

И тут возникает несколько проблем.

1. Во-первых, я так и не понял, какая input_shape мне нужна.
2. Как я думаю, вытекающая из 1, появляется такой error:

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_input to have 2
>   dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 135, 240, 3)

Возникает она, собственно, на этой строке:

> line 19, in FitModel
>   self.model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=epoch, batch_size=32)

P.S

x_train - это numpy array изображений, заранее сохраненный в .npy.

y_train - это их классификация. Сохранен в этом же .npy.

Прошу помощи.

Answer (score 3):

У вас тут сразу несколько ошибок и "непоняток":

1. судя по размерности входного тензора вы пытаетесь обучить модель на одной картинке - этого, мягко говоря, недостаточно. Для хороших результатов надо 2000+ картинок - чем больше, тем лучше.
2. обычно картинку сначала преобразовывают в черно-белую - в результате получается один цветовой канал, вместо трех. Кроме этого еще скалируют значения, разделив тензор на 256.
3. если все картинки в обучающей выборке (после превращения в чернобелые) имеют размерность `(135, 240)`, то и модели на вход надо подовать тензор такой же размерности:

   ```
   self.model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1024, input_shape=(135, 240), activation="relu"))
   ```
4. функцию активации `sigmoid` используют только на последнем (выходном) слое в задачах **бинарной** классификации. На скрытых слоях лучше использовать `relu` или `keras.layers.LeakyReLU`.
5. непонятно откуда вы извлекаете `Y` (метка класса). Где и как у вас хранятся правильные (предразмеченные) метки классов?
6. оптимизатор SGD в наше время практически не используют. Попробуйте `adam` вместо `SGD` - SGD может очень медленно сходится или вообще не сойтись при неудачно выбранном `learning rate`

Comment: спасибо огромное за пояснение. К сожалению, появилась ещё одна ошибка, с которой я не могу справиться своими силами. Добавил её в вопрос.

Comment: @NoName_as_Null, не надо задавать 100-500 вопросов в одном SO вопросе. Это не принесет пользы никому кроме вас. Если у вас возник  новый вопрос - откройте новый SO вопрос. ;)