# Как задавать размерность выборки при создании модели в Keras / Tensorflow?

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, keras, tensorflow

Всех приветствую ещё раз.

Пытаюсь обучить свою (почти первую) модель.

После первого вопроса мой NeuralNetwork стал выглядеть так:

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
import tensorflow as tf


class NeuralNetwork():
    def __init__(self):

        self.model = keras.models.Sequential()
        self.model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1024, input_shape=(135, 240), activation="relu"))
        self.model.add(keras.layers.Dense(512, activation="relu"))
        self.model.add(keras.layers.Dense(9, activation="softmax"))

        opt = keras.optimizers.Adam()
        self.model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=opt,
                      metrics=["accuracy"])

    def FitModel(self, trainX, trainY):
        self.model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=30, steps_per_epoch=2)


    def Predict(self, image):
        predictions = self.model.predict(image)

        choice = np.argmax(predictions[0])
        return choice
```

И основной файл так:

```
CountData = 7990

nn = NeuralNetwork()

WIDTH = 240
HEIGHT = 135
for i in range(1, CountData+1):

    file_name = 'D:/TrainingData/training_data-{}.npy'.format(i)
    train_data = np.load(file_name)

    img = np.array([i[0] for i in train_data])[0]
    label = np.array([i[1] for i in train_data])[0]

    img = img / 255


    nn.FitModel(img, label)
```

Но появилась уже другая ошибка:

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_input to have
>   shape (135, 240) but got array with shape (240, 3)

Что очень странно. Я несколько раз проверил форму img, она была (и остается) такой:

> shape: (135, 240, 3)

```
print(np.array(img).shape)
```

И форма label:

> shape: (9,)

```
print(np.array(label).shape)
```

Почему она на вход берет лишь форму (240, 3), а не (135, 240, 3)?

Что с этим делать? Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: А где ваш первый вопрос?

Comment: @0xdb, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/930623/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81-input-shape-%D0%B2-keras-expected-dense-input-to-have-2-dimensions-but-go

Comment: можете запаковать все ваши NPY файлы в архив и выложить на какой-нибудь файлообменник?

Answer (score 3):

Для начала предлагаю определиться с понятием выборка данных: выборкой является набор данных из, скажем, `N` экземпляров.

В подавляющем большинстве случаев выборка данных имеет размерность от 1 до 4:

- Размерность: 1D - вектор или список, состоящий из `N` значений (экземпляров), например числовой ряд вида: `[3, 18, -2, ...]`. *Размерность выборки*: `N`.
- Размерность: 2D - таблица (или список списков одинаковой длины), состоящая из `N` строк (экземпляров). Столбцы такой таблицы называют признаками (*features*). Пример: таблица описывающая антропометрические особенности человека для предсказания его пола: `рост`, `вес`, `размер ноги`, `объем талии`, `объем грудной клетки` для `N` человек (экземпляров). *Размерность выборки*: `(N, 5)`. 5 - число столбцов/признаков.
- Размерность: 3D - набор из `N` двумерных таблиц. Например `N` картинок в градациях серого (с одним цветовым каналом) с разрешением `(width, height)`. *Размерность выборки*: `(N, width, height)`
- Размерность: 4D - набор из `N` трехмерных матриц. Например `N` цветных картинок, где цвета заданы `RGB` кортежем (красная, зеленая и синяя состовляющие в каждой точке картинки).  *Размерность выборки*: `(N, width, height, 3)`.

Размерность 1D легко преобразовывается к размерности 2D - просто создаем таблицу, состоящую из одного столбца/признака. Таким образом из размерности `(N)` получается размерность `(N, 1)`.

В итоге осталось 3 варианта: `2D`, `3D`, `4D`.

**NOTE:** при описании размерности тензора данных (выборки данных) для создания модели в Keras, первая состовляющая размерности, отвечающая за число экземпляров (`N`), *не указывается*. Т.к. архитектура модели не должна зависеть от числа экземпляров выборки.

Таким образом для примеров указанных выше мы будем указывать следующие размерности в Keras:

- 2D: `input_shape=(5)` - 5 столбцов / признаков
- 3D: `input_shape=(width, height)` - *все* черно-белые картинки в выборке приведены к одинаковой размерности: `(width, height)`
- 4D: `input_shape=(width, height, 3)` - *все* цветные картинки в выборке приведены к одинаковой размерности: `(width, height)`

PS обратите внимание на то, что все наборы данных имеют строгие размерности. Т.е. все экземпляры выборки имеют одинаковое число значений. Напрмер мы не сможем передать таблицу в которой в разных строках не совпадает число столбцов. Другими словами, передать модели список списков неодинаковой длины не получится.